# Quick sort partitioning algorithm.How it works

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, quicksort, partitioning

This is a algorithm for partitioning in quick sort.

Let a=x[lb] (lb refers to lower bound) be the element whose final position is sought.
Two references up and down are initialized to the upper and lower bounds of the sub-array respectively.
At any point during the execution, each element in a position above up is grater than a.

Two references up and down are moved towards each other in the following fashion
Step 1: Repeatedly increase the pointer down by one position until x[down] > **=** a

Step 2: Repeatedly decrease the pointer up by one position until x[up] < a

Step 3: if up > down then interchange x[down] with x[up].
The process is repeated until the condition in step 3 fails ( i.e up =< down) at that point x[up] is interchanged with x[lb] ( which equal to a), whose final position was sought and j(i.e final position) is set to up.

**Using this algorithm I have to partition the array**

```
25,57,48,37,12,92,86,33
```

pivot is selected as the first element in the array.
Thus a=25.

Initially down=0,and up=7.
Since the condition x[down]>=a is satisfied down pointer doesn't have to be moved.
After decreasing up 4 times
down points to 0 and up points to 4.

Then interchanging x[down] with x[up]  I get

```
12,57,48,37,25,92,86,33
```

After increasing down once and decreasing up 4 times I come up with up=0 , down =1.
Then i have to interchange x[up] with x[lb].
Then I have 12,57,48,37,25,92,86,33 with j=up=0.

Is this correct.
?
Then when applied to quick sort algorithm I then have to do Quicksort(x,1,7).

That is I have to partition the array `57,48,37,25,92,86,33`

Selecting first element as the pivot a=57.

Then down=0,up=6.

Interchanging x[down] with x[up] 
I get `33,48,37,25,92,86,57`.
Repeatedly increasing down pointer 4 times and repeatedly decreasing up ointer 3 times I have `33,48,37,25,92,86,57`

Then down=4,up=3.
Interchange x[up] with x[lb]
I have `25,48,37,33,92,86,57`  j=up=3.

But clearly **this is not partitioned correctly around 57**.

I can't see what mistake I am making.Therefore if someone can help me to figure out this mistake that would be really helpful

Comment: `Repeatedly increase the pointer down by one position until x[down] >= a` - that should be `>` - after this you want to point at 57, which is greater than the pivot and should be swapped with an element that is smaller from the right-hand side of the array.

Comment: I am referring here to the left-hand index, of course.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError : So the error is in the algorithm right?

Comment: Yes, it basically goes like this: Increase the left-hand index for as long as the value it points at is less or equal than the pivot. Then decrease the right-hand index for as long as the value there is greater than or equal to the pivot value. If the indexes haven't met, swap the two values, increase/decrease the indexes, and repeat.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError does equality come in both less or ewual and greater or equal?This algorithm works fine if x[down]>a and x[up]<=a

Comment: There are a few variations in literature, but generally values equal to the pivot can go on either side.

Answer (score 2):

after interchanging x[down] with x[up] you have to update down and up too.
step 3 should be modified as:
Step 3: if up > down then interchange x[down] with x[up] **and down++ and up--**. The process is repeated until the condition in step 3 fails ( i.e up =< down) at that point x[up] is interchanged with x[lb] ( which equal to a), whose final position was sought and j(i.e final position) is set to up.